# Filter some words

Tags: php, arrays

I want to filter some reserved word on my title form.

```
$adtitle = sanitize($_POST['title']);
$ignore = array('sale','buy','rent');
if(in_array($adtitle, $ignore)) {
$_SESSION['ignore_error'] = '<strong>'.$adtitle.'</strong> cannot be use as your title';
header('Location:/submit/');
exit;
```

- How to make something like this. If
  user type `Car for sale` the sale
  will detected as `reserved keyword`.
- Now my current code only detect single keyword only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for a regular expression:

```
foreach($ignore as $keyword) {
  if(preg_match("/\b$keyword\b/i", $adtitle) {
    // Uhoh, the user used a bad word!!
  }
}
```

This will also prevent some false positives, such as 'torrent' not coming up as a reserved word because it contains 'rent'.

Comment: it should probably be case insensitive, too

Comment: What happends if user enter $keyword like \*abuse\*

Answer (score 4):

You could also try something like this:

```
$ignore = array('sale','rent','buy');
$invalid = array_intersect($ignore, preg_split('{\W+}', $adtitle));
```

Then $invalid will contain a list of all the reserved words used in the title. This could be useful if you wanted to explain *why* the title cannot be used.

**EDIT**:

```
$invalid = array_intersect($ignore, preg_split('{\W+}', strtolower($adtitle));
```

if you want case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 1):

```
function isValidTitle($str) {
   // these may want to be placed in a config file
   $badWords = array('sale','buy','rent'); 

    foreach($badWords as $word) {
        if (strstr($str, $word)) return false; // found a word!
    }
    // no bad word found
    return true;

}
```

If you'd like to match the words **only** (not partial matches as well, as in within other words), try this modified one below

```
function isValidTitle($str) {

       $badWords = array('sale','buy','rent'); 

        foreach($badWords as $word) {
            if (preg_match('/\b' . trim($word) . '\b/i', $str)) return false; 
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that flag the word "torrent" because of "rent"? Thats why I went regex with word boundaries.

Comment: @Erik Yeah but he didn't specify if partial words should be matched or not. He can replace with `preg_match('/\b' . $word . '\b/')` if he'd like to.

Comment: should probably be case insensitive also

Answer (score 1):

> $adtitle = sanitize($_POST['title']);
>
> $ignoreArr =
>   array('sale','buy','rent');
>
> foreach($ignoreArr as $ignore){
>   if(strpos($ignore, $adtitle)!==false){
>
> ```
>  $_SESSION['ignore_error'] = '<strong>'.$adtitle.'</strong> cannot
> ```
>
> be use as your title';
>
> ```
>  break;
> }
> ```
>
> } 
>   header('Location:/submit/');
>
> exit;

This should work. Not tested though.

Answer (score 0):

How about something as simple as this:

```
if ( preg_match("/\b" . implode("|", $ignore) . "\b/i", $adtitle) ) {
    // No good
}
```

Comment: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: will be there